# TypeScript module file not found

Tags: typescript, electron, node-modules, es6-modules

I am using TypeScript with Electron and I am trying to import another `.ts` file from the same directory as my main `index.ts` file, but I am getting the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` when running the app.

I am using `ES2020` as both  the compilation `target` and module system `module` in my `tsconfig.json`. Plus I am using `Node` module resolution.

I am importing my module like so:

```
import myDefaultExport from "./myModule";
```

Am I maybe missing the extension here? Is it needed? Why?

Comment: How are you exporting the module?

Comment: @Quarter `class myDefaultExport { ... }` and `export default myDefaultExport;` at the file end.

Comment: Above comment is not the recommended style for typescript. The better way would be `export class myDefaultExport { ... }` and import using `import { myDefaultExport } from “./myModule”` Some reasons can be found in Basarat’s book https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: @adamfsk well I changed it now, but it doesn't change the outcome. I still get the same error message.

Comment: One of your file references is wrong but there could be various places it could be incorrect. It could be in tsconfig.json, package.json, an html file, or your webpack/other build tool config, or even elsewhere!